# Remove duplicates in list of model objects

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a **list** from model objects ( *length about 1.5 million* ).

```
class Word(object):
    def __init__(self, id, word, arg1 , arg2 )
        self.id = id
        self.word = word
        self.arg1 = arg1 
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

There is many objects that have same `word` property but different `id, arg1, arg2`
for example :

```
1     hi        2      3
2     hi        4      6
3     hello     2      7
4     hi        2      7
5     world     1      9
6     hello     3      3
7     code      5      2
```

There is `hi => 3` and `hello => 2`

How can i check duplicate items by `word` property and remove them in a **fast way**
**Note that the length is too long**

Comment: I can't use DB in this section ... just list @Norrius

Comment: @ArashHatami no. Something else is making it look like you can only use lists, but really, Python uses ducktyping, so anything that *behaves* like a list will work. So: Use a proper data management tool (ORM, Pandas), see my answer.

Comment: Using drop_duplicates of DataFrame is much easier, if you have no problem in converting your list to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be using this 3rd-party library [toolz](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz)

In your case, you can use it like this:

```
import toolz

unique_words = toolz.unique(words, key=lambda w: w.word)
# unique_words is a generator object
```

**Output:**

```
>>> unique_words = toolz.unique(words, key=lambda w: w.word)
>>> for w in unique_words:
...     print(w.word)
... 
hi
hello
world
code
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply want a `set`. That's a container where only one object with the same key can exist. Here's the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

What you want to do is make your `Word` class *hashable*:

- it needs a `__eq__(otherword)` method that takes another word and returns true if the otherword's `.word` is equal to its own, and
- it needs a `__hash__` method that returns a hash of its content. I'd just `return self.word.__hash__()`.

Then, `set` makes sure each word is only in there once. You can also combine, cut, subtract sets like you can do it with mathematical sets (the things in curly brackets {} ).

A word about your application: At 1.5 million objects, it **really** looks like you should be having a table rather than a list of Objects, because that just means you really have about as much overhead per row in your table as content (if not even more).

Python's "Pandas" module is probably the tool to use here. It very likely obsoletes most of the stuff you've written so far.

Answer (score 2):

I find converting to a dataframe and using `drop_duplicates` easy.

Use:

```
DataFrame.drop_duplicates(subset=['word'], keep='first')
```

This will return a deduplicated dataframe deleting all rows having the same `word` property while preserving the first occurance.

- If you wish to drop duplicates except for the last occurrence, use `keep='last'`.
- To drop all duplicates, use `keep=False`.

Comment: Thank you but i can't convert `list` to `dataframe` in this project